# Mclust sigma output has different dimension from mean

Tags: r, mclust

```
Mclust(data)
```

produces output in which the mean has dimension of three, but sigma has a dimension of 1. This doesn't usually happen, but with certain data (all of the same type) it does. Any ideas? Thanks!

```
$pro
[1] 0.2692071 0.4183056 0.3124873

$mean
         1          2          3 
-0.4522930  0.9288538  1.8929688 

$variance
$variance$modelName
[1] "E"

$variance$d
[1] 1

$variance$G
[1] 3

$variance$sigmasq
[1] 0.2909666
```